# How do I add a button to the navbar?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, docusaurus

I've just started using Docusaurus and I want to add a Sign Up button to the navbar (yes, I know that it's for documentation only). I have tried `swizzle`ing the componenets but I've had no luck. I think it has something to do with this `react code`:

```
<Link
        className="button button--secondary button--lg"
        to="/docs/intro">
        Sign Up
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docusaurus supports adding buttons to the navbar by extending the default theme in a configuration file.

To add a simple signup button you can create a `docusaurus.config.js` file in the root directory of your site.

```
module.exports = {
  themeConfig: {
    navbar: {
      items: [
        {
          to: 'docs/intro',
          label: 'Signup',
          position: 'left',
          className: 'button button--secondary button--lg'
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank You! This was exactly what I'm looking for.

If I want to change the theme of the button to the default shade of green of Docusaurus, do I use custom CSS or something else?